# Poor Automatic C# Garbage Collector Performance with many C++ Interop Calls

Tags: c#, c++, .net, garbage-collection, interop

What could cause C# garbage collection to fail so miserably in my C# application doing lots of C++ calls when a well placed GC.Collect resolves the problem?  My C# app makes millions of C++ calls using System.Runtime.InteropServices DllImport and CallingConvention.Cdecl, and has some C# destructors to release some of the C++ unmanaged memory.  I am using .NET Framework 4.

1. What could cause the below code in my application to force paging to occur slowing execution to a crawl (consuming 29GB of RAM on my 32 GB system and taking more than 4 minutes before I kill the process) while just changing the `ManualGC` to `true` caps memory usage at about 600MB and execution completes within 29 seconds?
2. Why does leaving `ManualGC` `false` and changing `Write` to `true` cap memory usage at about 12 GB and allow execution to complete in about 59 seconds without paging?

Snippet of some code in my application (obviously with some names changed):

```
private static int callCount = 0;
private const bool ManualGC = false;
private const bool Write    = false;

internal static void CommonlyCalled()
{
    ++callCount;

    if ( callCount % 100000 == 0)
    {
        if (ManualGC)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        if (Write) Console.WriteLine(HandleErrorsCallCount);
    }

    DoLogic();
}
```

Memory is measured with the "Memory (Private Working Set)" column in Windows Task Manager.  Behavior is consistently repeatable.

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the code that calls the C++ library.  Can you create C# wrapper classes that implement `IDisposable` and clean up unmanaged stuff in `Dispose()`?

Comment: If you're using finalizers to release unmanaged memory, you must keep in mind that finalizable objects are only collected and finalized in the most heavy-duty and most infrequent generation 2 GC sweep (your two GC lines are the magic to trigger it). Finalizers in C# don't run when objects go out of scope, as destructors do in C++.

Also, as a general rule of thumb, if you find yourself triggering GC manually, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: It seems like I need to add some well placed calls to Dispose to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> and has some C# destructors to release some of the C++ unmanaged memory

That isn't enough if your wrapper is small and your C++ code requires a lot of memory.  You just don't put enough pressure on the GC to get it to call your finalizers soon enough.  Implementing IDisposable to fix this is boilerplate.  But not a complete solution, you should tell the GC about that so it can do something about it.  Some code to play with:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
            new Wrapper();
        }
    }
}

class Wrapper {
    private const int alloc = 10 * 1024;    // C++ object memory usage
    private readonly bool useamp = false;   // Change this after testing
    private IntPtr mem;

    public Wrapper() {
        if (useamp) GC.AddMemoryPressure(alloc);
        mem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(alloc);
    }
    ~Wrapper() {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mem);
        if (useamp) GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(alloc);
    }
}
```

Observe the memory usage of this program while you run it.  On my machine, private bytes builds up to about half a gig.  Now change `useamp` and run again, you'll see it is *much* more efficient, requiring only 4 MB.  Without having to call Dispose :)  Tested on Win 8.1, .NET 4.5.1, you might get very different results on an older .NET version.

The value you pick for *alloc* isn't that critical, it only needs to be in the ballpark.  Apparently you do need much more than 10KB.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are relying on a user-defined finalizer for proper behavior in your C# application. You need to update your C# code to address the following specific problems with this scenario:

1. You should not be using user-defined finalizers<sup>1</sup> (a C# method with a syntax like C++ destructors). If you have an unmanaged resource which you need to clean up, create a class which extends `SafeHandle` to wrap just the handle to the resource.
2. Your code should be written to always explicitly call `Dispose()` on the `SafeHandle` instances which wrap your unmanaged resources when you are done using them. Never rely on a finalizer in C# to perform your cleanup operations.

<sup>1</sup> This statement holds true enough of the time that the following is all but a rule to live by:

> If you write a user-defined finalizer in C#, you probably did something wrong.